# Adding interactive bubble to highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to add interactive bubbles to [highchart](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts)? I am using a multi-axis line graph and want to show a bubble/badge above a certain X point. The bubble shows the number of aggregated system-events and catch any clicks.

[image: interactive bubble]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add an additional `bubble` series, for example:

```
series: [{
    ...
}, {
    type: 'bubble',
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.customValue}'
    },
    minSize: 20,
    maxSize: 20,
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'customValue'],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return this.point.customValue
        }
    },
    data: [
        [2, 22, 1],
        [4, 22, 20],
        [5, 22, 1]
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z14pamfy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble